# Laravel excel export how to export conditional data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to export partial data from my table not all data, I am using Maatwebsite [plugin](https://laravel-excel.com/)

I have tried below code in controller

```
public function report(Request $request)
{
       
     
        $sdate  = $request->query('sdate');
        $edate  = $request->query('edate');
       
        
       
        $report = Report::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $sdate)
                                   ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $edate)
                                   ->get();
        

        
       return Excel::download($report, 'report.xlsx');

 }
```

In this time I am getting empty excel file.

I am able to get all data after creating app/export

like below

**app/export/ReportExport.php**

```
public function collection()
{
        return Report::all();
}
```

but how I can I do it in controller ? or how can I sent $report data controller to collection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the FromQuery concern provided by the package.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Report;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class ReportExport implements FromQuery
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($start, $end)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Report::query()->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $this->start)
                              ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $this->end);
    }
}
```

Then from you controller, you can call it

```
return (new ReportExport($sdate, $edate))->download('report.xlsx');
```

I have not tested the code. So apologies if I made a mistake. You can refer to [official documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html#from-query).

There are also other methods of exporting which you can find from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by doing this way.

> Step 1:  in your controller

bind `$request` in **Report-Export Class**. add code in method where you are calling **export excel**.

```
return Excel::download(new ReportExport($request), 'report.xlsx');
```

> step 2:

```
protected $request;
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function collection()
 {

  $request = $this->request  ;  
  return User::where('customer_id',$request->cId)->get();
 }
```